# How to extend one tensor with another. So the result contains all the elements from the 2 tensors, see example

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, tensor

```
a =  tensor([   [101,  103],
            [101,  1045]
        ])


b =  tensor([   [101,  777],
            [101,  888]
        ])
```

How to I get this tensor c from a and b:

```
c = a + b =  tensor([   [101,  103],
            [101,  1045],
            [101,  777],
            [101,  888]
            
        ])
```

With python lists this would be simply `c = a + b`, but with pytorch it just simply adds the elements and does not extends the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html) function:

```
c = torch.cat((a, b), dim=0)
```

Such as in the following example:

```
from torch import tensor
import torch
a =  tensor([   [101,  103],
            [101,  1045]
        ])


b =  tensor([   [101,  777],
            [101,  888]
        ])
c = torch.cat((a, b), dim=0)
print(c)
```

with output:

```
tensor([[ 101,  103],
        [ 101, 1045],
        [ 101,  777],
        [ 101,  888]])
```

Comment: Awesome. is there also a simple way to pad them to equal length, adding the same elements lets say 100 at the end?

Comment: Yes, `torch.nn.functional.pad()`

Comment: Still it does not work when tensors a and b do not have the same dimensions. And have not idea how to use torch.nn.functional.pad() for that. There is no usable example of torch.nn.functional.pad() that i saw.

Comment: @Brana you can look at the docs here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.pad.html

Comment: I solved with torch.nn.ConstantPad1d. Pytorch documentation is very bad and confusing without any real example in most cases.

Comment: thanks for advice, it helped to solve the problem but still it took me 2-3 hours